# Adding the android-support-v7-appcompat library?

Tags: android-sdk-2.3

New to Android, trying to follow the training tutorials step by step, but riddled with errors, what a mess!

First stumbling block on:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

The instruction to add the library reads:

Quote:
"Add the library to your application project:
    In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
    In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.
    In the Library pane, click the Add button.
    ..."

There is no Add button to be found in the Libraries pane in the Java Build Path, but several Add Jar, Add library and other buttons, none of which will solve the errors in Mainactivity.java.

After looking around I found that opening the Projects pane and use the Add button there resolved the errors and I could run the app. However getting problems in the next steps...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a question/answer site, where people post questions about problems they're having with their code or programming tools, and we try to find answers. What exactly is your question here? I don't see one anywhere. What can we help you with specifically?

Comment: "However getting problems in the next steps..." seems to be the question part of this. Could you expand on that? And probably delete the rest as it's not relevant to the question I think you have